# How to add an adobe font to worpdress WITHOUT a plugin and WITHOUT using @import

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts, adobe

I'm attempting to add a specific Adobe Font to my WordPress site without resorting to a plugin. However, following Adobe's article "[Add fonts to your website](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/add-fonts-website.html)", results in [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com) saying the default embedded link is using @import, which I want to avoid.

I'm using the most current version of WordPress (5.2.2). I subscribe to Adobe CC (I have an account). I can't download the font files so I'm unable upload them. I've already created a "Web Project" which contains the font I want to use. I am inserting the default embed code in the header.php file of my theme (placed in my child theme folder) between  and . And I've tried finding answers on Google, YouTube, and by contacting an Adobe Support agent (they don't have support for this), all with no luck.

This is the default embed code produced by Adobe for my Web Project:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/webprojectID.css">`

webprojectID is just here as a generic example.

I expected to use this font without using the @import, which Wordpress no longer recommends because of the additional loading time it adds.

Comment: If you can't download the font then you're pretty much stuck with the stylesheet Adobe provided you if you don't want to embed the font via JS, as @samuhay below suggests.

Comment: @cabrerahector
I am open to try embedding the font via JS, but I don't see samuhay's suggestion below. How would I go about embedding?

Comment: It seems samuhay deleted his/her answer for some reason. This is what they were talking about: https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/embed-codes.html#JavaScriptembedcode

Answer (score -1):

Create fonts folder in your child theme and upload your font file.

Then add this code to you child theme functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_name_enqueue_styles' );

function my_child_theme_name_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-font', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/font.ttf' ); 

}
```

Comment: Not possible with Adobe Fonts.